# How to lazy evaluate functions in a sequence in Scala

Tags: scala

Let's say I have three functions in a class that can return a Option[File]. I am looking for a nice way to execute them in order and stop when the first function evaluates to a Some (similar to what pick() does but with lazy evaluation), i.e. I don't want to use nested if-else statements.

```
abstract class Foo() {
  def first(): Option[File]
  def second(): Option[File]
  def third(): Option[File]
  def pick(): Option[File] = {
    Seq(first(), second(), third()).find(_.isDefined).map(_.get)
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter to `Option.orElse` is passed by name, so you can just use that to chain your methods:

```
def pick(): Option[File] = first orElse second orElse third
```

Answer (score 2):

```
scala> def f1:Option[Int] = {println("1"); None}
f1: Option[Int]

scala> def f2:Option[Int] = {println("2"); Some(2)}
f2: Option[Int]

scala> def f3:Option[Int] = {println("3"); Some(3)}
f3: Option[Int]

scala> f1 orElse f2 orElse f3
1
2
res0: Option[Int] = Some(2)
```